# UIBarButtonItem segue to next viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I created a UIBarButtonItem programmatically and want it to go to the next ViewController when it is pushed.

This is how I create the custom UIBarButtonItem in the viewDidLoad:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *foundButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Found it!"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(foundView)];
```

After that I created this method:

```
-(void)foundView:(id)sender {

 UIViewController *foundVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"foundView"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:foundVC animated:YES];
}
```

The ViewController where I want to go after the UIBarButtonItem is clicked has a Storyboard ID: "foundView".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code like this :

```
UIBarButtonItem *foundButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Found it!"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(foundView:)];
```

you forgot `:` after `foundView` in your selector so you don't call the method.

Comment: and have a look to the answer of @nhgrif too

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `segue` from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`.  Note, this `segue` connects two view controllers.  Not a button to a view controller.  Now, on the storyboard, give the **segue** a descriptive name.  For example: `segueFoundView`.

Now, do this:

```
-(void)foundView:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueFoundView" sender:self];
}
```

Edit: corrected spelling

Comment: In case anyone is doing a copy/paste, it should be `performSegueWithIdentifier`.